# Need help on solving the issues associated with npm run lint, in React js application

Tags: html, reactjs, json, vite

So i facing a situation where i have to solve these problems when i run npm run lint: [first lot of issues when ran npm run lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9GzK.png) [second lot of issues when run npm run lint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKI9n.png).

My project structure looks like: [project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6L45.png),

The main code includes:

src/App.jsx;

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Pet from "./Pet";

const App = () => (
  <div>
    <h1>Adopt ME</h1>
    <Pet name="Luna" animal="dog" breed="Havanese" />
    <Pet name="Pepper" animal="dog" breed="Cocktail" />
    <Pet name="Doink" animal="cat" breed="Mixed" />
  </div>
);

const container = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, container);
```

src/index.html;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Adopt me!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root">not rendered</div>
    <script type="module" src="./App.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

src/Pet.jsx;

```js
const Pet = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{props.name}</h1>
      <h2>{props.animal}</h2>
      <h2>{props.breed}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Pet;
```

,

.eslintrc.json

`````json
{
    "extends": [
        "eslint:recommended", "plugin:import/errors", "plugin:react/recommended", "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended", "prettier"],
    "rules": {
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": 0
    },
    "plugins": ["react", "import", "jsx-a11y"],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaVersion": 2023,
        "sourceType": "module",
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx":true
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "es6": true,
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        },
        "import/resolver": {
            "node":
            {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"]
            }
        }
    }
}
,

package.json;
````json

{
  "name": "adopt-me",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "preview": "vite build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\" --quiet",
    "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "4.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.6.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "prettier": "^2.7.1",
    "vite": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  }
}
`````

,

vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  root: "src",
});
```

I tried running commands to solve the issues such as:
eslint --fix C:\Users\HP\Desktop\adopt-me\src\dist\assets\index-CKKic4LZ.js

and eslint "src/**/*.{js,jsx}" --quiet --fix
however they don't seem to solve the issues (1oo issues when I run npm run lint)

How do I solve the issues when I run npm run lint? Any answers, solutions or suggestions?